# Weird array situation with FileReader, ArrayIndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, arrays

I want to give up, but I have to do it, so you're my last hope. I guess it's an easy problem, but I can't see what's wrong. Here's the code:

```
    int i = -1;
    String[][] dan = new String[20][13];
    try {
     FileReader odczytanie = new FileReader("Kontrahenci.txt");
     BufferedReader bufor = new BufferedReader(odczytanie);
     String str;
     str = bufor.readLine();
     System.out.println(str);
     while ((str = bufor.readLine()) != null) {
        i = i + 1;
        String[] ar = {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null};
        ar=str.split("; ");
        for(int j = 0; j < 13; j++)
            dan[i][j] = ar[j];
        for(int j = 0; j < 13; j++)
            System.out.println(dan[i][j]);  
     }
     bufor.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
           System.out.println("File Read Error");
        }
```

So when I try to run it I receive this error:

```
"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1"
```

for this line:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 13; j++)
    System.out.println(ar[j]);
```

In a file I have three lines with words split by semicolons. The code works perfectly for the first line, but after I receive the error. No idea what's wrong.

Comment: You have magic numbers (20, 13) in your code. Replace those with constants.

Comment: The 2 lines you mention are not available in the above code...

Comment: Set your debugger on the line that throws and inspect the contents (and size) of ar, and the value of j that fails.

Comment: If the file has more than 20 lines, `i` will index outside of `dan`. If a line has less than 12 semicolons, `j` will index outside of `ar`. If a line has more than 12 semicolons, `j` will index outside of `dan`.

Comment: @home Oh, yeah, my bad, i'm sorry. It should be  

for(int j = 0; j < 13; j++)
            dan[i][j] = ar[j];

Comment: What, if anything, are you doing with `dan` other than printing it? By the way, please update the question with the correction instead of burying it in a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard coding 13 seems a bit suspicious. The values you set for `ar` are overwritten by the assignment to split. ar doesn't necessarily have 13 fields any longer. What about

```
for (int j = 0; j < ar.length ; j++)
```

or even better

```
for (String s: ar)
```

That data must somehow be malformed or not what you're expecting. Try asserting the right size or printing it.

Also as Jerry noted, fixed size arrays are bad practice. You'd be better off with some higher-level collections like a List of HashMaps or something else that grows automatically.

A stop-gap would be to check that `i < 20` before indexing with i and then throw an exception or an assert. That'll point you in the right direction. You could also add it to your while loop, but that may leave data unread.

Comment: That will fix the problem for `ar` but not `dan`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have two mistakes, one with 13 and second with textfile. It takes me about 2 hours thinking and you make it so quick, eh ;]

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] ar = {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null};
ar=str.split("; ");
```

This declaration of `ar` with 13 null values will immediately be overwritten by `str.split("; ");`, thus you can't assume that the size of the array will always be 13. Instead of using 13 as the upper bound of your for loop i would recommend using `ar.len`or trying a for each loop.

I suspect you will have the same `IndexOutOfBoundsError` for your `dan` array as well.

You should avoid using magic numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You should either figure out how many lines are in the file before creating your array or switch to something that allows the size to change:

```
ArrayList<String[]> dan = new  ArrayList<String[]>();
try
{
    BufferedReader bufor = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Kontrahenci.txt"));
    while (bufor.ready())
    {
        dan.add(bufor.readLine().split("; "));
    }
    bufor.close();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    System.out.println("File Read Error");
}

for(String[] ar : dan)
{
    for(String s : ar)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

I didn't change your error handling, but note that you won't call `close` if there's an exception.